# MVVM and Entity Framework: Fields in model class is not always present in database

Tags: database, entity-framework, mvvm, model

I am using MVVM and Entity Framework and have a model class mapped to a database table called `EmplTable`.

In this class I have a few fields and we are shipping this product to a few customers and it varies a bit what fields are present in their database table `EmplTable`.

These are the fields present in my `EmplTable` model class:

```
    public string EmplId
    {
        get { return this.emplId; }
        set { if (this.emplId != value) { this.emplId = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EmplId"); } }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { if (this.name != value) { this.name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    }

    //Bare NAV_Name og ikke Name når axaptaversjonen ikke er 4.1
    public string NAV_Name
    {
        get { return this.nav_Name; }
        set { if (this.nav_Name != value) { this.nav_Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NAV_Name"); } }
    }

    public string DataareaId
    {
        get { return this.dataareaId; }
        set { if (this.dataareaId != value) { this.dataareaId = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DataareaId"); } }
    }

    public string NAV_StampId
    {
        get { return this.nav_StampId; }
        set { if (this.nav_StampId != value) { this.nav_StampId = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NAV_StampId"); } }
    }
```

But one customer doesn't have the `Nav_Name` field, others doesn't have the Name field for instance. I can of course do some ifs and stuff and create different model classes for the different `EmplTable` versions and just map the correct table for the current customer to the `EmplTable`. But it would be nice if I could specify that some of these fields is not present or that some of the fields is not mandatory.

I am not doing queries against the fields that doesn't exists in the different customers `EmplTable`, but I still get these "Invalid Column Name" errors.

For instance I get invalid column name if the `EmplTable` in the database doesn't contain `Nav_name` when I do this query:

```
    public EmplTable GetByIdAndFirma(string id, string firma)
    {
        return this.context.Employees.Where(p => p.EmplId == id && p.DataareaId == firma).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I guess this is because of the mechanism of Entity Framework or something, but is there any settings so that I can specify that some of the fields is not mandatory?